# AngularJS - How to filter a bunch of certain IDs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to create a filter that hides e.g. three certain IDs given.

My data object look like that:

```
$scope.subtree = [{id: 1},{id: 2},{id: 3},{id: 4},{id: 5},{id: 6},{id: 6}]
```

I get the command to hide:

```
[{id: 1},{id: 4},{id: 6}]
```

Template

```
<ul>

   <li ng-repeat="node in subtree"> 
        <p>node.id </p>
   </li>

<ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use filters, or a function on a scope.

```
data-ng-repeat="node in subtree | idFilter:[1,4,6]"

data-ng-repeat="node in subtree | filter:hideIds([1,4,6])"
```

Something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/zoltan_papp/a5h2wxmj/)