# JS - Array, only push certain values

Tags: javascript

There is an array A of numbers. Certain values that are stored in array B have to be filtered out. The result shall be stored in array C.

JS

```
var a = [ 1,2,3,4,5,6];

var b = [ 2,4,6];

var c = []; // shall contain all values of a except the ones from b
```

Here's my approach:

```
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){ 
  if(b.indexOf(a[i]) === -1){
    c.push(a[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes? What's your question?

Comment: iot does not work for me, maybe because my array consists of too many objects, I'mdoing a mistake

Comment: Your code works perfectly. What's the problem? http://jsfiddle.net/v7wxwa7v/

Comment: Your code will fail only if there's a type mismatch - your `a` array contains strings, for example, but `b` has only numbers. Now you have a choice - either cast `a[i]` into the type of `b` array, or use the hash approach shown in my answer.

Comment: It seems the question is a follow-up to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25787010/angularjs-how-to-filter-a-bunch-of-certain-ids). @user2952265 - why have you accepted that answer if it didn't solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over `a` and check against `b`

```
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (b.indexOf(a[i]) === -1) c.push(a[i]);
}
```